# Consume RESTful webservices using SPA framework

Tags: angularjs, web-services, backbone.js

I would like to have a lightweight application which will consume RESTful web-services. No more business logic.

I already implemented the same using CodeIgniter REST client. But still doesn't know how to handle the same using Backbone/AngularJS. I'm worried to show the web-service URL to public.

How can I call a web-service in backbone or angular without showing
the web-services URL to public. How can I hide the web-service URL? How are zoho/asana handling the web-service calls? Is it possible to hide/encrypt the web-service URL?

How secure is this using Angular or Backbone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend trying to hide or encrypt the web service URL. If your program can find and decrypt it, then anyone else can.

I suggest you protect the API with an API key or some other sort of authentication. With an API key, you can generate a hash on the server side that can be returned to the browser. The browser doesn't see the API key itself, just the hash. The API can then evaluate the hash to ensure it matches.

Including a timestamp can ensure that the hash can't be reused indefinitely. See the following for an example: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/rest-api-authentication-schemes

Comment: but this web services URL can be prone to BOT attacks. Is this okay ??

Comment: A well-architected API key scheme should be secure against brute-force attacks. The server itself may be at risk for DDOS attacks, if you think that is an issue.